# Dataframe groupby produce a group twice

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm using groupby in pandas dataframe, but it unexpectly produces a dataframe:

```
new = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
import numpy as np
new.groupby(np.arange(len(new))//2).transform(lambda x: print(x, type(x), '***'))
```

The outcome is

```
0    1
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
   0
0  1
1  2 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> ***
2    3
3    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
4    5
5    6
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
6    7
7    8
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
```

But my expectation is

```
0    1
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
2    3
3    4
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
4    5
5    6
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
6    7
7    8
Name: 0, dtype: int64 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> ***
```

Where does that dataframe object come from?

Comment: What version of pandas? I believe this was fixed in a recent release

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), which include this section:

> **Notes:**
>
> In the current implementation apply calls *func* twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if *func* has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.

You called `transform()`, but that is just another version of `apply()`. Also, it turns out this caveat exists for both DataFrame and GroupBy objects.

That explains why you're seeing the first group twice, first as a Series and then as a DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
new.groupby(np.arange(len(new))//2)[0].transform(lambda x: print(x,'****'))
```

Notice the **[0]**.

The output will be:

```
0    1
1    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64 **** (2,)
2    3
3    4
Name: 1, dtype: int64 **** (2,)
4    5
5    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64 **** (2,)
6    7
7    8
Name: 3, dtype: int64 **** (2,)
8     9
9    10
Name: 4, dtype: int64 **** (2,)
10    11
11    12
Name: 5, dtype: int64 **** (2,)
```